# REMOVE THE LAST COMMA in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

COUNTNUM is a column name in a table that has data like below
1,2,3,4,

I used

```
RTRIM((COUNTNUM),',')  COUNTNUM
```

It didn't work

Desired output 
1,2,3,4

Current output
1,2,3,4,

Any suggestions would greatly help..!
Thanks

Comment: This SQL proves your solution works: `with p as ( select '1,2,3,4,' as countnum from dual) select RTRIM((COUNTNUM),',')  COUNTNUM from p;`.  There must be something else in `COUNTNUM` after the comma (in which case Hellmar's answer probably won't work either.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak your solution worked but am placing rtrim in a cursor                                                                                                   
       OPEN cursor FOR
                select orderid,display,itemlist,RTRIM((COUNTNUM),',') 
         COUNTNUM 

               FROM table1 t
                   WHERE t.id = '2';

Comment: Right... what I am saying is that if `COUNTNUM` really ended with a comma, it would be working.  There must be something in `COUNTNUM` after the comma -- a space or something.  You can try to select `DUMP(COUNTNUM)` to get a detailed view of what's really there.

Answer (score 2):

REGEXP_REPLACE((countnum), ',$', '')

Comment: If there are spaces after the comma, maybe this: `REGEXP_REPLACE((countnum), ',[ ]*$', '')`

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak or use `TRIM` function as follows: `REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(countnum), ',$', '')`.

Answer (score 0):

**Perhaps There are non-digits after the comma which needed to be removed**

Logic is added to account for possible non-digits between the comma and the end of `countnum`.

Explanation:

`[^[:digit:]]` is the negation of the digit character class

`*` is a quantifier meaning zero to many

`$` is an anchor identify the end of `countnum`

```
SCOTT@dev>WITH d AS (
  2      SELECT
  3          '1,2,3,4, ' countnum
  4      FROM
  5          dual
  6      UNION ALL
  7      SELECT
  8          '1,2,3,4,'
  9      FROM
 10          dual
 11  ) SELECT
 12      countnum,
 13      regexp_replace(
 14          countnum,
 15          ',[^[:digit:]]*$'
 16      ) mod_count_num
 17  FROM
 18      d;

COUNTNUM       MOD_COUNT_NUM  
1,2,3,4,       1,2,3,4        
1,2,3,4,       1,2,3,4
```